# Android setOnClickListener does not work

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I've a little problem with my toast in android :/ 
I want to create a little toast when `button1` is going to be activated

here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.andruiden.toast;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import com.andruiden.toast.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //Klick Listener
    class MeinClickListener implements OnClickListener{
        public void onClick(View v){
            String text = "Es wurde geklickt";
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

            t.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Button beim Hörer registrieren
        MeinClickListener t = new MeinClickListener();
        Button test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        test.setOnClickListener(t);

      }
}
```

On the line `test.setOnClickListener(t);` i get the error:

```
The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type view is not applicable to the arguments
```

What does it means?

I can change the code to this here:

```
test.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) t);
```

But when i run the .apk on my galaxy s2 it happens nothing.. :/

sorry for my bad english xD

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you do not set an onClick in the layout file? Adding `android:onClick"YOUR_METHOD_NAME"` to the button's layout information does exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please remove these lines from you import section:

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
```

these are dialog interfaces

and use this instead:

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

your class should be:

```
    class MeinClickListener implements OnClickListener
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        String text = "Es wurde geklickt";
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        t.show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have subclassed the wrong `OnClickListener` (you've got click listener from `DialogInterface`).

First of all, get rid of `DialogInterface` imports and replace your click listener subclass with:

```
//Klick Listener
class MeinClickListener implements View.OnClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        String text = "Es wurde geklickt";
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        t.show();
    }
}
```